# Distributing docker based application for on premise installation

Tags: docker, installation

I am trying to create an easy way for end users to deploy a docker based application that we have built. Our main problem is that the images for the system to run reside in a private docker registry and the end users are essentially non technical who need to have this ability to install and uninstall the system easily.

The system needs to run on both linux and windows environments. I have looked hard but have not found a solution that creates a simple installer which can take care of all dependencies and get the system up and running.

What is the right way of creating such an installer.
I do understand that there is always a way to create a MSI package for windows and a RPM or DEB for linux but i want to know what is the best practice for the same as i have never done this before.